# Cant see add button for vm extension on new azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-vm-role

Cant see add button for vm extension on new azure portal. I want to add dsc extension for my windows vm on new azure portal but there is not Add button on extension configuration.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUOTo.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not yet possible to add extensions to existing VMs in the new portal. We can imagine that it will come soon.
The mechanisms you can use is set-azureRmVMExtension with the extension and the parameter info which can be found at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-extensions-configuration-samples-windows/. This has schema information for Puppet, Antimalware and other extensions.

I hope this answers your question.
Regards

Comment: Yes i know through command line it is possible I was looking if it is issue with my subscription or vm or it is not available. Thanks for reply

Comment: It's not an issue with your subscription. If that helped, can you please validate my answer?